# How do I get the staff of magnus back if I lose it?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I had my staff of Magnus in my Lakeview manor in Skyrim. I accidentally removed the DLC, and the house with everything got removed, along with my staff.

Can I still get it back? I need it for another quest. I have no idea how I would get it back.

I'm playing on Xbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reload any save at the part before you stored the staff, but not so far. The content will still be remove, but the staff will be safe in your possesions. If you're on PC, using cheats to get it back.

Comment: But it was a long time ago that it happened

Comment: I do not have a save that goes back far enough

Comment: @Benjaminward are you on the PC version? If so, use cheats to add it into your inventory. If you're on console, there's nothing else you can do.

Comment: Why dwonvotes? There's nothing else to put there that's the only solution.

Comment: Figured out j didnt need is

Comment: He said he was on xbox in the title.